# Very long delay before events fire on ionic elements in real device

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

When I have more than 5 `ion-button` elements on the same page and use the `(click)` binding to handle events, it takes over 3 seconds, sometimes almost 5 seconds for the event to fire. This problem only occurs when I'm running the app on a real device (Android only; I haven't tested on iOS). Running the app in browser causes no such issues.

My app is fairly complex with 20 pages or so, but on the pages where I use less elements, the events fire normally without the 3 - 5 seconds delay.

This issue was raised on Github in 2017 (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12817) but the Ionic team simply closed it without any solution or potential walkarounds. Quite frustrating.

Does anyone know how to solve this or is the Ionic Framework simply not a practical solution to develop real world apps? Solutions on the internet suggest using `(tap)` instead of `(click)`, while others suggest using `tappable (click)`. None of these work.

Comment: I haven't had this sort of problem so I think it must be something happening with you particular implementation. I did have issues with big lists before and some slowdowns with user interactions stemming from that. Need to know a bit more about what you're doing

Comment: Mate, tappable don't have any effect on click iself, and click is very fast and is response is like native time, but even in native apps(java/kotlin ,swift/objective c) click performance can be delayed 3 seconds if code is bad (bad means that in code you may use much if statements so if's become complicated and thus code execution will take time, but in hybird apps , other than the code itself compication, there is design interface also , since using much ngIf's will make delay for page to render and maybe if ngif related to button clicks will also affect, and click is better than tap), and...

Comment: ... And using javascript in typescript could make delays( if the code could be written by typescript but you wrote it in javascript cause lack of ts knowlage will make delays even if typescript will be converted to js on render ..), if you have too much if's in your code change them to switch , and if you want to be sure of click use a function and inside it put alert('something'); and test this fuction click on real device and see if there is delay, if there was delay then its bug related to instalation of framework, else will be from your code

Comment: @MostafaHarb One of the buttons with the delays is exactly like `<ion-button (click)="showSearch = true" [hidden]="showSearch">` with a single `ion-icon` inside. It doesn't even reference a function in the `.ts` file, it simply changes the value of one variable.

Comment: You missunderstood me, you can put them in design put not in conflecting way, they are made to be put for sure but not in big amount in single html...

Comment: @wcjord The elements with the delays are not in a generated list, simply hard coded buttons in the UI. I do generate lists, but I no issues coming from them.

Comment: @MostafaHarb, I did understand you, but can you explain what is causing the delay with that one particular button? You can see the entire code it runs, so maybe you have a clue where the issue is coming from?

Comment: No there should be 0 delay in your code with this code, till now i've made like 13 apps with ionic through 2 years and in all of them the performance was perfect and didn't face such a glitch as yours, maybe try to reinstall ionic cli or cordova or angular cli , since maybe a bug of specific deprecation is causing the delays...

Comment: @MostafaHarb I will reinstall all the latest versions of these 3 right now, build it and give feedback how it goes.

Comment: Ok and i'll be waiting tour request...

Comment: @MostafaHarb I did update all the components, and no changes. After running `ionic cordova build --prod`, I zip up config.xml, www, and resources, and upload them to build.phonegap.com to compile them into an APK and sign it. Could this be causing the problem? I use `cli-8.1.1` with PGB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out what the exact issue was but, after running `ionic build` locally, then uploading these resources to Phonegap build, the issue would be present.

However, I decided to install the latest Android Studio and started building locally. Strangely, this solved the problem.